# Multiple interpolations in P5js

Tags: loops, interpolation, p5.js, lerp

I'm trying to create multiple interpolations in p5js and for that purpose I tried to re-create Ben Fry's Integrator class in javaScript. I realize that transition and conversion from processing to p5js is quite difficult so if this is not possible, I would appreciate if you gave me a hint for doing it in another way. Thank you.

Here is what I have done so far. . .

```
   function Integrator(value, damping, attraction)
{
  this.DAMPING=0.5;
  this.ATTRACTION=0.2;

  this.value;
  this.vel;
  this.accel;
  this.force;
  this.mass=1;

  this.damping=this.DAMPING;
  this.attraction=this.ATTRACTION;

  this.targeting; //boolean
  this.target;

  this.value=value;
  this.damping=damping;
  this.attraction=attraction;

  this.set =function(v)
  {
    this.value=v;
  }

  this.update = function()
  {
    if(this.targeting)
    {
      this.force +=this.attraction *(this.target-this.value);
    }

    this.accel = this.force/this.mass;
    this.vel = (this.vel+this.accel)*this.damping;
    this.value +=this.vel;

    this.force=0;
  }

  this.target = function(t)
  {
    this.targeting=true;
    this.target=t;
  }

  this.noTarget = function()
  {
    this.targeting = false;
  }

}
```

Here is also the link to the original processing code by Ben Fry
http://benfry.com/writing/map/Integrator.pde

Comment: You didn't really ask a question. What does this code do exactly? Which line behaves differently from how you expected it to?

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding. My question in not why the code is not working, this was just sharing of what I have done. My question is how to implement multiple interpolations in p5js. If I remember correctly, I wont be able to do it in a loop since it will run then give you the final result. So I was wondering if such thing is possible in p5js.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the class to JavaScript (see below) is relatively straightforward. Though one thing to watch for is variables and functions with the same name, as this is not allowed in JS. You can see the [demo here](https://editor.p5js.org/rednoyz/sketches/Kdy8GKriU)

```js
class Integrator {
  
  constructor(value = 100, damping = 0.5, attraction = 0.2) {
    this.force = 0;
    this.vel = 0;
    this.accel = 0;
    this.mass = 1;
    
    this.damping = damping;
    this.attraction = attraction;
    
    this._value = value;
    this._target = value;
  }

  value(v) {
    if (typeof v !== 'undefined') {
      this._value = v;
      return this;
    }
    return this._value;
  }

  update() {
    if (this.targeting) {
      this.force += this.attraction * (this._target - this._value);
    }

    this.accel = this.force / this.mass;
    this.vel = (this.vel + this.accel) * this.damping;
    this._value += this.vel;

    this.force = 0;
  }

  target(t) {
    if (typeof t !== 'undefined') {
      this.targeting = true;
      this._target = t;
      return this;
    }
    return this._target;
  }

  noTarget() {
    this.targeting = false;
  }
}
```